# Can I add some variables to my chart.js in page know that variables?

Tags: javascript, express, chart.js, handlebars.js

This is my callback function and i have getData(data); to get all JSON data ,
And created dataset = [ ]; (for get some specific properties from my all JSON data)

```
function call_some_api(getData){
    request('https://someUrl..........',{json:true},(err,res,data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }     
        if (res.statusCode === 200){
        
             var dataset = [];

             data.forEach((value, key)=>{
             dataset.push(value.close);

            });                
           getData(data);     
        }
    });
};
```

And use callback and pass my all JSON data in res.render it works normally.
***But i want add dataset variable from my callback into res.render to page know variable dataset***

```
app.get('/chart',function(req,res){
    call_some_api(function(getAPI_data){
       
        res.render('chart',{
            dataChart: getAPI_data,
            
        });
    });
});
```

I just need to my /chart page (handlebars template) know my variable from callback function. (for build chart)
This my /chart (handlebars template)

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<br><br>

<script>

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
 
           // I just want add in this line below.
            data: dataset,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                stacked: true
            }
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

This error  [image]

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html scroll down to "Route parameters". I believe that's what you are looking for

Comment: I'm just a newbie, i have no idea. Can you give me some example ? thank sir. @JeremyThille

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I understand that I'm asking a very wrong question. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I apologize for the wrong question by myself. Now I just edited the post.

Comment: You don't need to apologize that much :) Maybe the question was just a bit ambiguous

Comment: Yes i know, Thank sir. I just want to build chart with JSON data api from my callback function and add some variable from my callback into dataset: in chart.js code, But i dont know what to do.

Comment: @LiaHoney Of course this does not work. Handlebar syntax for accessing properties is `{{dataset}}`, you try to access the arraydirectly, which is at runtime undefined, `dataset` get treaten as a js variable. Not sure if it is possible what you want, have you tried `data: {{dataset}},`?

Comment: I have tried it, and error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','

Answer (score 1):

You mean like a second argument, analog to `getAPI_data` ?

```js
function call_some_api(getData){
    request('https://someUrl..........',{json:true},(err,res,data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }     
        if (res.statusCode === 200){
        
             var dataset = [];

             // BTW this can be better/cleaner done with `.map` ;)
             data.forEach((value, key)=>{
             dataset.push(value.close);

            });                

           getData(data, dataset);   
  
        }
    });
};
```

And in your render/http endpoint

```js
app.get('/chart',function(req,res){
    call_some_api(function(getAPI_data, dataset){
       
        res.render('chart',{
            dataChart: getAPI_data,
            dataset
        });

    });
});
```

NOTE: Code not tested, inline edited.

Comment: Yes i mean that, it's look good idea and i have tried it. I add dataset in my page /chart (handlebars template) in tag <script> for chart.js (i just want to build chart) and website is error Uncaught ReferenceError: dataset is not defined. Can you help me ? Thanks sir.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question above is beyond the scope of the post. Thanks for the great idea I think it can take me to the next step.

Comment: put a `console.log` before `res.render` and see if its defined/has entrys. Provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I put it console.log(dataset); before res.render as you said , error still is dataset is not defined, But the dataset is work in my vsCode terminal.

Comment: Then you have some problem within your handlebars template

Comment: Can you help me look ? ,  I'll edit to add my handlebars template.

Comment: I just added the code handlebars template, thanks for the help.